# Why is the edit 80 posts badge called Strunk and White?

Tags: support, badges

When one edits 80 posts on math.stackexchange.com he/she gets a badge called "[Strunk and White](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)".

Can someone tell me why this badge has been given this name?

Thank you.

Comment: Strunk and White are names of people who authored a style guide. [Also this](http://xkcd.com/923/).

Comment: Uh, I had read the answer but didn't realize it was their names. That's quite the coincidence then...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi out of idle curiosity, what else did you think it was?

Comment: @quid I thought "strunk" referred to striking through words, and "white" referred to whiting out words...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Strunk_and_white&redirect=no).

Strunk and White is the common name for "The Elements of Style", a guide to writing style dating all the way back to 1918.

The notion is (in my own interpretation) that a user who submits 80 edits of others' posts must surely enjoy writing, or he/she wouldn't bother.  In other words, such an editor would, with a high probability, have a good grasp of the elements of style of writing in English.